# Session timeout extending for delay between request and response

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to implement a session timeout warning popup. I am making an ajax call. Suppose session-timeout is set as 'T' in web xml. In java layer i am using thread sleep for 'T-15 seconds', so on getting a response back i am showing a session timeout warning popup. The problem is my session timeout is extending for 'T' time once i am getting response back. While i have checked documentation where the system idle time or last activity is calculated on basis of request received on server. 
Any suggestion on how to calculate server idle time only on request received at the server and not the response sent through.